# peewee.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I'm trying to create a relational database but when the constructor is called I get the following error `peewee.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed language.content_id`. I have tried on many different ways to get this done but there is a problem when calling `models.Language.create()`. The other calls to insert into the tables work just fine. Any ideas how can I fix this? Please help.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class User(UserMixin, Model):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    email = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField(max_length=100)
    joined_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
        order_by = ('-joined_at',)

    def get_post(self):
        return Post.select().where(Post.user == self)


    @classmethod
    def create_user(cls, username, email, password, admin=False):
        try:
            cls.create(
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=generate_password_hash(password),
                is_admin=admin)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise ValueError("User already exists")


class Post(Model):
    content = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE

class Category(Model):
    category = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE

class Language(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    content = ForeignKeyField(rel_model=Post, related_name='contents')
    category = ForeignKeyField(rel_model=Category, related_name='topic')
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User,
        related_name='units'
    )
    language = TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = DATABASE
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/new_post', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def post():
    form = forms.PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.Post.create(content=form.content.data)
        models.Category.create(category=form.choice.data.strip())
        models.Language.create(user=g.user._get_current_object(),
                               language=form.language.data.strip())
        flash("Message posted! Thanks!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('post.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `content=some_post_obj` when you call Language.create()

Comment: Hi @coleifer. I have the content as a ForeignKeyField that's why I'm not setting `content=some_post_obj`.

Comment: Uhh that's exactly why you *should* set it.

Comment: I still got an error. But it doesn't make sense to me to call two times the create content method, with the Post model and the Language model. Is this how it should be?